# Entity reference multi level links in Views

Tags: entities, nodes, views

I have 3 content types **Speaker**, **Sub-category** and **Category**.

On the **Category** detail page i would like to put a block-view with a contextual filter to show **Speakers** linked to that specific **Category**, but there is no direct reference link between those 2.

There are only 2 reference fields:
 - **Speaker** -> **Sub-category**
 - **Sub-category** -> **Category**

Is it possible (trough views UI?) to make this 2-step connection?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, add two relationships and link it through that. The one relationship will connect to the contextual filter and the other to the content type filter and the relationships will link together (sub-category reference of Speaker to sub-category reference of Category)