# Do multi-level multi-value relationships work in a view?

Tags: views, 8

In Drupal 8, I have a content type **Story**, with a multi-value entity reference to content type **Project**, which, in turn, has a multi-value reference to **Team-Member**, which has a single-value reference to **Person**. In my story node, I want to show a list of projects, and within each, a list of team members.

I have an embedded view (content type **Story**), to which I'm passing the nid as a contextual filter, with 3 relationships defined: referenced **Projects**, referenced **Team-Members**, and referenced **Persons**. I've added fields from all 3 types, each using the correct relationship, I'm pretty sure.

I'm getting **Project** fields correctly, each **Project** in a row. But I'm not getting anything for **Team-Members** or **Persons**.

Am I asking this view to do something views can't do, by having multi-value references 2 levels deep? Is there a better approach? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

> Am I asking this view to do something views can't do, by having
>   multi-value references 2 levels deep?

Yes, to my knowledge there is no way to go 2 levels deep for this scenario.

One possible solution, to work around this constraint, would be to use [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) and...

1) Create a team member view that uses the project nid as a contextual filter.

2) Add the project nid (content id) as field to your original view so you can pass it to the views field view.

3) In original view, add a views field, select the team member view you created in Step 1 and pass it the project nid (content id).

Comment: Thank you for validating my conclusion! I considered Views Field View, but the twig solution (see my answer) is working pretty elegantly for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

After spending a day trying to make this work as an embedded view, I decided to take another approach. Given that my need here is specific to a particular page template, I just wrote a nested loop in twig, with a couple of tests to replicate filters the view would have applied. Much simpler for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same challenge, and I was able to set up multi-level relationships - thanks to another [article](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/175107/entity-reference-multi-level-links-in-views) on this platform.